# Pdf-latex with python script, custom python variables into latex output

Tags: python, variables, latex, pythonanywhere

I currently have the following code which works to produce a PDF output. Is there a better way of writing up the content for the PDF, other than done here? This is a basic pdf, but am hoping to include multiple variables in later versions. I have inserted variable x, defined before the PDF content, into the latex pdf. Many thanks for any advice you can give.

[PDF Output - image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/82WRc.jpg)

````
import os
import subprocess

x = 7

content = \
r'''\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[margin=1cm,landscape]{geometry}
\title{Spreadsheet}
\author{}
\date{}
\begin{document}''' + \
r'This is document version: ' + str(x) +\
r'\end{document}'


parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('-c', '--course')
parser.add_argument('-t', '--title')
parser.add_argument('-n', '--name',)
parser.add_argument('-s', '--school', default='My U')

args = parser.parse_args()

with open('doc.tex','w') as f:
    f.write(content%args.__dict__)

cmd = ['pdflatex', '-interaction', 'nonstopmode', 'doc.tex']
proc = subprocess.Popen(cmd)
proc.communicate()

retcode = proc.returncode
if not retcode == 0:
    os.unlink('doc.pdf')
    raise ValueError('Error {} executing command: {}'.format(retcode, ' '.join(cmd)))

os.unlink('doc.tex')
os.unlink('doc.log')```
````

Comment: Have you checked the pylatex module ?

Comment: Yes, and I find it uncessarily complicated. For example even defining one’s own commands is difficult (doc.append(Command('Hello', arguments={'one'}, options=['two'] )))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As explained in [this video](https://youtu.be/LufMPezEN6Y), I think a better approach would be to export the variables from Python and save them into a `.dat` file using the following function.

```py
def save_var_latex(key, value):
    import csv
    import os

    dict_var = {}

    file_path = os.path.join(os.getcwd(), "mydata.dat")

    try:
        with open(file_path, newline="") as file:
            reader = csv.reader(file)
            for row in reader:
                dict_var[row[0]] = row[1]
    except FileNotFoundError:
        pass

    dict_var[key] = value

    with open(file_path, "w") as f:
        for key in dict_var.keys():
            f.write(f"{key},{dict_var[key]}\n")
```

Then you can call the above function and save all the variables into `mydata.dat`. For example, in Python, you could save a variable and call it `document_version` using the following line of code:
`save_var_latex("document_version", 21)`

In LaTeX (in the preamble of your main file), you just have to import the following packages:

```latex
% package to open file containing variables
\usepackage{datatool, filecontents}
\DTLsetseparator{,}% Set the separator between the columns.

% import data
\DTLloaddb[noheader, keys={thekey,thevalue}]{mydata}{../mydata.dat}
% Loads mydata.dat with column headers 'thekey' and 'thevalue'
\newcommand{\var}[1]{\DTLfetch{mydata}{thekey}{#1}{thevalue}}
```

Then in the body of your document just use the `\var{}` command to import the variable, as follows:

```latex
This is document version: \var{document_version}
```